# Bitcoin 101, need some knowledge

Tags: blockchain, address

I am new to bitcoin. How do I check if my blockchain is working? I have tested some free bitcoin sites but neither of them have worked.

Comment: What do you mean with "your blockchain"? Do you wish to know whether your client is up to date with the status of the network, or are you asking how to test whether your blockchain.info account is able to receive bitcoin transactions? As it is, this question is not clear. That's why I am downvoting it, and voting to close as "unclear what you are asking". Please improve your question, then flag for reopening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can understand you entered your bitcoin address to some faucets, but do not receiving nothing from it? You should check https://blockchain.info/ and enter your bitcoin address in "Search" field. If someone sent you something, you'll definitely see transaction there.

Comment: If you don't own the private keys you don't own the coins. Faucets pay out en masse - if at all - so don't expect your work to be rewarded as advertised.